# Do I have to make one control class per use case in class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case

I'm making class diagram based on ECB pattern.
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary), every use case is represented as a control class.
Does this mean a 1:1 response?

For example, if I made 'Login' and 'Register' use cases, then does 'LoginController' and 'RegisterController' have to be there?

Can I integate them into 'ValidationContoller?'

I looked up information about the ECB, but it was hard to get detailed information. Thanks in advance for any helps.

Comment: That's purely opinion based. Nobody will force you to do so. And vice versa. Aaand - Login is no use case since it has no added value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no need for a one-to-one mapping at all.

As laid down in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary) article:

> ECB classes are **first** identified when use-cases are analyzed:
>
> - every use case is represented as a control class;
> - ...
>
> The classes are **then** refined and re-structured or reorganized as needed for the design, for example:  ...

So the 1:1 is only the beginning of the analysis, and in no way a guidance for the implementation.

It is important to understand that this pattern originated in the 90's in a pre-agile context.   Ivar Jacobson, the inventor of the use-cases,  intended with ECB to be able to derive an implementation from the requirements (represented as use cases), and to keep a perfect traceability of the implementation back to the requirements. If you look for more details on this approach, you may read the *Unified Software Development Process* by Jacobson, Booch and Rumbaugh.

***Not related**: It may be useful to know that Jacobson's more recent work (e.g. [Use Case 2.0](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/sites/default/files/field_iji_file/article/use-case_2_0_jan11.pdf)) no longer mentions ECB, since modern agile approaches do not support the kind of upfront analysis assumed with ECB.*